# Allow S3 hosted App exclusive permission to upload files to public bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, kotlin, amazon-s3, aws-cdk

I have a static React App I have deployed using Cloudfront - hosted within an S3 Bucket. I would like the user to have the option to upload files in the future, through this app, to the bucket but I am a little confused on the permissions side.

I have created the Bucket with the CDK like so...

```
        val siteBucket = Bucket(
            this, "SiteBucket",
            BucketProps.builder()
                .bucketName(SITE_DOMAIN_NAME)
                .websiteIndexDocument("index.html")
                .publicReadAccess(true)
                .removalPolicy(DESTROY)
                .build()
        )
```

I have additional config using the CDK to hook up the CloudFrontWebDistribution and to route the traffic to my domain.

My understanding of the above is that `.publicReadAccess(true)` allows my Bucket to be accessible to the wider internet - but that it doesn't grant any rights to upload to the bucket.

However, how do I use the CDK to grant permissions for only my static webapp to upload to the Bucket - but not for anyone else to upload?

(I've been reviewing this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/permissions.html but unsure of the best practise e.g. can my app have a role or permissions assigned to when the app itself is just the contents of a bucket. Do I need to create an Access Point? But again, how do I limit my app to have permissions - is this even possible with a static app or do I need a backend/Lambda to invoke first?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For one, you don't need publicReadAccess.  You can just grant access to the OAI.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-access-to-amazon-s3/

This is a pretty good starting point for the page though:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/allowing-external-users-to-securely-and-directly-upload-files-to-amazon-s3/

Not sure you necessarily want to use the same bucket to upload to and host your site.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @court-schuett - going to need to have a good read through those links - appreciate it!